# Bugzilla 3.6 with Netbeans 6.8

Tags: netbeans, plugins, bugzilla, incompatibility

When I tried to configure bugzilla with netbeans 6.8 a msg told that the bugzilla's version was newer than the netbeans' plugin compatibility.
I've been searching and can't find any updated plugin (and it is not in the plugin manager, at least for what I saw)

Any idea where to find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a bit late, but I found a version number in a bug report: 3.2.2

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=173040